# Low Cost Online SQL or mySQL training?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a Lotus Domino programmer who is in between consulting jobs - not by choice the consulting job market really sucks right now.

With some extra time on my hands I would like to receive some SQL training as a resume booster and to expand my skill set.

SQL is something I have used in the past, but I need a way to document my knowledge on my resume.

Can anyone recommend a source of low cost SQL or mySQL training?

Derek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the lowest cost training you can get is just reading books from your library or Amazon (links below) and practicing at home.  Practice makes perfect!

There is:

[Learning MySQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596008643)

[MySQL 5.0 Certification Study Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328127)

[MySQL in a Nutshell (In a Nutshell (O'Reilly))](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596514336)

Answer (score 1):

If you are really looking for a cheap way, community colleges around my area are offering whole semester MSSQL (exam 70-431 outline) classes. Typical class would have 4 units (in California, community colleges charge $20/unit). Most of these classes are online, so flexibility and convenience are there schedule-wise.

You could go to 4-day bootcamps but those would usually cost $2-3K per class.